# Shell: Multiple arguments in a single variable

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, csh, tcsh

I have
`var="arg1"" arg2"" arg3"` and I want to use it against a a command as such below

`java $VAR"`

And the above works, but I read that the safer way for variable substitution is quoting it and hence I tried

`java "$VAR"`.  The problem with this is that all the arguments get treated as one argument.

I read a lot of solutions that talk about using arrays, but that is limited to Bash like shells. Some talked about `eval` but from the number of comments to that I have come to know it's insecure. Some talked about setting a different `IFS` - I thought about reading `IFS` and using that to separate my `args` in `$VAR`. But the `IFS` on that system already had space in it.(So at a loss here about that).

Is there a cross-shell approach to achieve what I want, in a safe way? Or should I roll back to just `java $VAR`

Comment: *How* cross-shell? Portable to ksh, zsh and bash (but not `/bin/sh`), you have arrays, which are *really* the Right Thing. There's a *reason* everyone else supports arrays -- because you *need* them to write correct code.

Comment: Well if I leave it as unquoted variable, it will work everywhere right?

Comment: ...only for a very limited value of "work". See [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) describing the limitations.

Comment: Honestly, it's *possible* to use `eval` safely, it's just a lot of trouble to go through to get all the details right. (For example, Python's `shlex.quote()` function or its Python-2 predecessor `pipes.quote()` can generate strings that are safely `eval`able by any POSIX-compliant shell, but you then need to do the work of getting your pushed through a Python interpreter running the appropriate transform before any situation where it could possibly be substituted into code).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Agreed. Thanks for Bash FAQ, wonderful read.